# 2010 Malibu Turn signal doesn't always switch on

Tags: chevrolet

Then turn signal for the left works most of the time when you push down on turn signal arm but the right signal arm rarely ingages the right signal light to stay on. If you hold the arm you can kept the light bliking.
Sounds more mechanical than electrical.
Thanks anyone that has an idea.

Comment: Probably the turn signal switch in the stearing column is going bad.